# Burninate tag: sorting algorithms

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags for sorting (the problem) and algorithms should cover it. What additional signal does having one combined tag convey?

Answer (score 2):

Tag list does not show [sorting-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting-algorithms) so this can't be a relevant problem. If there are single instances, I vote for replacing them with [sorting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) + [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) as proposed.

Comment: I suggest making it a synonym for sorting for future cases.